# Using Ninject in asp.net mvc GenerateUserIdentityAsync to add custom claim

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, ninject.web.mvc

I need to add custom claims when a user signs in (external sign in from Google) by performing a read to the database and adding the values returned. I am using Ninject for dependency injection to inject controllers with interfaces to my business layer services.

So I have located the identityModels.cs method to add claims:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        string userId = userIdentity.GetUserId();

        //var _iUserBLL = (IUserBLL)System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUserBLL));
        //UserBO objUser = _iUserBLL.GetById(userId);

        //userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Value1", objUser.Value1));
        //userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Value2", objUser.Value2));
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

Here the System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService line fails and causes it to crash. This works elsewhere and I've also tried the same approach I use to inject controllers like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserBLL _iUserBLL;

    public MyController (IUserBLL iUserBLL)
    {
        _iUserBLL = iUserBLL;
    }
}
```

And even:

```
[Inject]
    public IUserBLL _iUserBLL { get; set; }
```

But when used in the GenerateUserIdentityAsync method the _iUserBLL is null. Any ideas how I can inject my IUserBLL to make a custom database call here?

A bit more info - if you aren't familiar with this method, it's part of the Identity code generated in a visual studio project with individual user accounts.

The full class is like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
       GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

So I tried the constructor in here, which doesn't work:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        private readonly IUserBLL _iUserBLL;

        public ApplicationUser (IUserBLL iUserBLL)
        {
            _iUserBLL = iUserBLL;
        }
...
}
```

The IdentityUser is declared in the inner workings of the pre supplied identity.entityframework class and is called from within that which I can't edit, so I'm confused how to approach this?

Thanks for your reply Sam, it put me onto a solution. Here is the code I ended up with. I had trouble with the static 'Create' method so I used the [Inject] attribute instead. Is there a way to alter the static 'Create' method to use IUserBLL in the constructor? Here is the code that I have working:

In App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs

```
// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        [Inject]
        public IUserBLL _iUserBLL { get; set; }

        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {

            var userIdentity = user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);

            UserBO objUser = _iUserBLL.GetById(user.Id);

            userIdentity.Result.AddClaim(new Claim("Claim1", objUser.Value1));
            userIdentity.Result.AddClaim(new Claim("Claim2", objUser.Value2));

            return userIdentity;

        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

In my NinjectWebCommon.cs I also include these lines, extra to all my bindings:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
kernel.Bind<System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current.User).InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()).InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToMethod((context) =>
            {
                var cbase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                return cbase.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            });
...
}
```

Comment: If the method is being called from somewhere where you can successfully inject the interface in question, then pass it as a method parameter

Comment: Why don't you do constructor injection for IUserBLL in the class containing your GenerateUserIdentityAsync method same as you do in constructor?

Comment: Cheers, I added a bit more info above. Ideally I'd like to just have `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Inject]
        public IUserBLL _iUserBLL { get; set; }`
But _iUserBLL is always null. Am I missing something in NinjectWebCommon.cs to tell Ninject to inject this?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationUser` is an entity object and this kind of objects are responsible to holding data not doing logic. It will be much better if you add your custom claim in `UserManager` rather than `ApplicationUser`. Consider this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager: UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IUserBLL _iUserBLL;

    public ApplicationSignInManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, 
         IUserBLL iUserBLL)
        : base(store)
    {
        // if you already fully integrated Identity with ninject, 
        // ninject could automatically resolve this for you.
        _iUserBLL=iUserBLL;
       // other configurations here
    }

    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(
         ApplicationUser user, 
         string authenticationType)        
    {
        var userIdentity=await base.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType);
        UserBO objUser = _iUserBLL.GetById(userId);

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Value1", objUser.Value1));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Value2", objUser.Value2));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, this worked for me, I've updated the post with the code I ended up with. I had to use [Inject] because of the static create method, that seem okay?

Comment: Since `ApplicationSignInManager` is not necessary to register in Owin context. You could get rid of the static method by letting ninject initializes `ApplicationSignInManager` instead of Owin context and remove its registration from the `Startup.Auth.cs` file.

Comment: While the changes worked for the IdentityConfig method when signing in, it's the IdentityModels method that is called to regenerate the identity (from Startup.Auth), so I lose the username when this occurs. So I'm back to square one, how to inject into the ApplicationUser method to use my IUserBLL in IdentityModels.cs, GenerateUserIdentityAsync?

Comment: @Bluemoon So instead of adding your extra claims in the `SignInManager`, put them in the `ApplicationUserManager` then. See my update post.